# Question about deadweight social burden triangle. Error in the test?

Tags: microeconomics, externalities

I have been trying to answer the following question for the past two hours. I've looked at textbook examples, online resources and lecture notes. There seem to be two correct answers but I may be wrong. I think both b) and c) are the correct answers to this question. I am assuming that the *deadweight social burden triangle* is *the deadweight loss triangle*.
However, only b) is stated as the correct answer.

**When does a *deadweight social burden triangle* occur?**

```
 a) The social marginal benefit equals the social marginal cost.

 b) The social marginal benefit is greater than the social marginal cost.

 c) The social marginal benefit is less than the social marginal cost.

 d) The price is zero.
```

Can anyone please explain the reasoning behind b) being the correct answer (if it is)? Thank you.

Comment: Social efficiency is co-ordinated at SMC=SMB. Both (b) and (c) refer to instances of positive and negative externalities respectively. Instance (b) may occur from a COVID vaccine. Whereas, (c) happens for more predictable reasons regarding negative externalities. Either way, for a public economists, the ambition would be to achieve an outcome where SMC=SMB. This is socially efficient (a fundamentally different concept from technical efficiency).

Comment: @EB3112 thank you. I understand that, but I do not understand why b) is the correct answer.

Comment: Bed time for me in the UK here economajor. I personally couldn't offer a more concise answer than the one I provided, however I welcome you to check out this link.https://courses.byui.edu/econ_150/econ_150_old_site/lesson_11.htm#:~:text=A%20deadweight%20loss%20also%20exists,optimal%20output%20is%20not%20achieved.

Comment: @EB3112 thanks again. I read this one, it has another example, if you scroll up a bit it says this too: "As is, the excessive quantity of output creates a deadweight loss to society since the marginal social cost exceeds the marginal social benefit" In that case, c) is also the correct answer, is not it?

Comment: I think personally you'd get more from just e-mailing the lecturer, rather than me speculating on whether there is an error in the answer bank.

Comment: @EB3112, thanks. But, there is no lecturer to ask for help. I would do so should there be a lecturer. There is also no trace of this question online. I do not know the source of this question. Thus, I had to post for assistance. I have the question and the answer. There is no explanation.